# Make 2 links same height in columns?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a setup where i have a unordered list on a page with `x <li><a href="#">Link text</a></li>.`

They are via CSS set to 50% width each, so that i have 2 items on each line.
My problem is that 2 links on one line, can vary in height as they have different link text.
My question is; how can i, via jQuery, set the same height for each  (the a is styles with a border bottom, so it would look best if they alined) on the same line? But not all  in the sections should have the same height, only on a "pr line" basis.

Hope it makes sence :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aSJSm/1/

And here is the code:

`<html>` :

```
<ul>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item1 bla bla bla</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item2</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item3</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item4 ala bala bala</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item5</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item6</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item7</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item8</a></li>
</ul>​
```

`<css>` :

```
ul{
 width: 200px;   
 float:none;
}
ul li a{
 width: 50%;   
 float: left;   
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;    
}​
```

`<javascript>` :

```
var setList = function(){
    var listItems = $('ul').children();
    $.each(listItems, function(index){
        if (index % 2 == 0){
            var leftElementHeight = $(this).children('a').height();
            var rightElementHeight = $(this).next().children('a').height();
            if (leftElementHeight < rightElementHeight)
                $(this).children('a').css("height", rightElementHeight);
            else
                $(this).next().children('a').css("height", leftElementHeight);
        }    
    });
}
setList();​
```

Make sure you included in $(document).ready(function(){}) and you have latest jquery.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to achieve is called a ***grid layout*** with ***variable row height***. And the only way to do this in HTML is the table element.

If you really want to do this, you will have to sacrifice the semantic of your markup on the altar of the beauty of the result.

What you should do is create a two column table and put the content of your former `li` elements in the `td` elements of the table. Use the vertical-align property of the td and their style properties to match your design needs.

Comment: I fiddled with a javascript solution for a while and it kind of works, but this is the most elegant answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this in jQuery you can do it like this:

```
​$('li:even').each(function(){ 

    var leftHeight = $(this).height();
    var rightHeight = $(this).next().height();

    var newHeight = (leftHeight <= rightHeight) ? rightHeight : leftHeight;

    $(this).next().andSelf().height(newHeight);

});​​​​​​​​​​
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/svenhanssen/VEnXp/

Answer (score -1):

Set an Id or class for 2 links. And set height using following method.

```
$("#id").css("height", '100px');
```

Comment: He said the list items have variable height.